# R: missing interaction in summary table, binomial GLM + type iii errors

Tags: r, bioinformatics, generalized-linear-model

I am confused as to why my summary table is missing `NeonicfCLO` and `Treatment:NeonicfCLO`?

[image]

I guess it has something to do with the intercept but I am not sure!

```
Neonicf<-factor(neonic$Neonic)

whole <- glm (cbind(Correct, Incorrect) ~ Treatment + Neonicf + Treatment*Neonicf, data=neonic, family=binomial, type="III")
summary(whole)
```

Here is a sample of my data. Apologies about the formatting, stack overflow does not seem to like excel tables

```
Neonic  Treatment   Correct     Incorrect
CLO        0           9            2
CLO        0           8            3
CLO         0          8            5
IMD 0   5   1
IMD 0   11  4
IMD 0   9   4
IMD 0   10  3
IMD 0   9   6
IMD 0   12  2
IMD 0   9   5
IMD 0   5   10
THX 0   9   2
THX 0   7   3
THX 0   13  2
THX 0   8   4
CLO 2   9   4
CLO 2   10  4
CLO 2   7   4
CLO 2   10  5
CLO 2   7   4
CLO 2   9   3
CLO 2   8   4
IMD 2   10  1
IMD 2   10  1
IMD 2   9   5
IMD 2   9   4
IMD 2   7   3
IMD 2   9   3
IMD 2   5   7
IMD 2   10  4
IMD 2   9   1
IMD 2   6   2
IMD 2   6   5
IMD 2   11  5
THX 2   10  1
THX 2   7   3
THX 2   10  5
CLO 10  4   6
CLO 10  6   6
CLO 10  8   5
CLO 10  5   2
CLO 10  8   3
CLO 10  8   6
CLO 10  6   7
IMD 10  6   3
IMD 10  7   4
IMD 10  8   5
IMD 10  4   6
IMD 10  5   8
THX 10  8   5
THX 10  7   3
THX 10  7   7
THX 10  2   9
```

Comment: You should read about [contrasts](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-and-interpreting-different-contrasts-in-linear-models-in-r/).

Comment: Because these are the reference levels, and are your intercept.

Comment: Somewhat of a side comment, but 1) What does *type='iii'* do in an lm or glm call?  2) Why is your output for an *lm* call with a *family=binomial* option?  Does that make sense?

Comment: This is a very common question for people getting used to R.   To understand why the *summary* output makes sense, make up appropriate values for each of your IV's or IV dummy variables, and you will see that you can calculate your DV from the output of *summary*.  You might also be interested in applying `library(car); Anova(whole)` and `library(emmeans); pairs(emmeans(whole, ~ Neonicf))`